# Output integral point in or on the boundary of the circle which has the largest distance from the center

Tags: java, c++, geometry, point

After an interview, I had this question and util now I don't have any good idea to resolve it.

Given a circle on a two-dimentional plane
Output integral point in or on the boundary of the circle which has the largest distance from the center. The coordinates of center and radius are floats.
Could any geeks give me some suggestions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because as this is more a math problem than a programming problem

Comment: No, it is a computing problem if the question is interpreted in a specific way. For example, if the center is at (1.1,1.1), what pixel (or pixels) are the farthest from the center but not outside the circle for a radius of 2.33? One has to be wary of roundoff errors and floating point representations here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your circle is at `(X,Y)` with radius `R`.

1) generate a list of all possible `x`s:

```
xList=[ceil(X-R):1:floor(X+R)]
```

2) search for potential `y`s:

```
yUpperList=Y+sqrt(R^2 - (xList-X).^2)
yLowerList=Y-sqrt(R^2 - (xList-X).^2)
```

3) shrink `y` candidates to integers

```
yUpperList = floor(yUpperList)
yLowerList = ceil(yLowerList)
```

4) re-compute distances

```
distance=sqrt([yUpperList;yLowerList].^2 + [xList;xList].^2)
```

5) find the maximum distance:

```
maxDistance = max(distance(:))
```

This gives you `O(R)` complexity.

I guess the solution size scales linearly with `R`, so I don't think you can do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a place to start, don't be afraid to think about "a bad way that will probably work".

This is more of a maths/logic problem than a computing one, and once you have an idea of how you would do this "by hand" given infinite time, implementing it in terms of a programming language should be the easier part of the solution.

For example...

Our strategy could be:

Enumerate all the "integral points" that are in a square bounding the circle (inefficient, but thinking about this will get your brain into gear at least).

1)
write a function that outputs a list of all points in this square.
In C++, you might want to implement

```
struct IntPoint{ int x; int y; };
std::vector<IntPoint> getPointsAroundCircle(float center, float radius);
```

2) Loop through all of the points.
Figure out which of those points are actually in (/on) the circle, and "remember" which point had the largest distance. You might want to implement the following helper function:

```
float distance(float center, float radius, const IntPoint & p);
```

Hint: How does knowing the distance of a point from a circle's center help us decide if it's inside the circle?

Note: calculations (or rather comparisons) involving floats/doubles are subject to rounding considerations. You may want to compare using some kind of "epsilon" as a tolerance. 
Some reading material if you're interested:
https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

3) Once you have gone through all the points, you'll know which point's x, y coordinates to print.